# Most efficient way to import data from one MySQL database to another

Tags: mysql, import, load-data-infile

I'm writing a PHP script which imports data from tables in two different databases into another one. I've got it working ok with sample data, except now I've moved to using data closer resembling its final use: 25+ million records per table, and growing daily. Obviously, efficiency is a bit of a concern.

Here's how it current works. I copy the table structure, adding a couple of extra fields to maintain key integrity:

```
other1.someTable (field1, field2, field3) Pk = [field1, field2]
other2.someTable (field1, field2, field3) Pk = [field1, field2]
mydb.someTable   (id, source, field1, field2, field3)
    Pk = id, Unique key = [source, field1, field2]
```

And here's the SQL. It has a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement because this import needs to be done regularly, updating the data in "mydb". Thankfully, records won't be deleted from the "other" database (i think!).

```
INSERT INTO mydb.someTable (source, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT 1, field1, field2, field3 FROM other1.someTable
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = field1, field2 = field2, field3 = field3;

INSERT INTO mydb.someTable (source, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT 2, field1, field2, field3 FROM other2.someTable;
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = field1, field2 = field2, field3 = field3;
```

My question is this: **Is this the best possible way to do this?** Are there any other methods which might be faster, considering there are going to be millions and millions of records, totaling many gigabytes of data per table?

Comment: Do you have shell access? There is a MySQL tool called mysqldump.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure there are no duplicate IDs? Or, if there are, are you always going to overwrite them with data from the second database?

Additionally, do you do **any** processing on the data you obtain from DB1 / DB2 prior to inserting / updating it into 3rd database?

If the answers are "yes" to the first question and "no" to the third, it will likely be **a lot** faster to use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/load-data.html). Select data from DB1 and DB2 and load them in sequence.

Comment: unfortunately the answers to the 1st and 3rd questions as "no" and "yes".

Comment: So what kind processing do you need to do then? As far as duplicate IDs go, if you're using your `source` column to distinguish, you can very much keep doing that.

Comment: mostly trimming data, sometimes changing type (string to date, string to int, etc)

Comment: Fair enough. Is there some way for you to determine what records have been added / changed in DB1 / DB2 since last sync (something like `lastUpdated` timestamp on record, for example)? That would (presumably) reduce the number of records that have to be copied over. Beyond that, use batch updates if you can (not sure what you're using to process the data on the back end) and, if using InnoDB, be sure to commit / restart transaction every 1000 records or so (you can play with that number a bit to see what gives best performance)

Answer (score 0):

Well on your On Duplicate Key Update, there is not need to update field1 and field2 as they are the key and have been matched.

The other question is: do you care if 1 sets field3 to one value and then 2 sets it to another -- and again tomorrow, and the day after -- is this something to know happened?

Comment: the data from the "other" databases won't overwrite each other since there is the "source" column to make it unique per DB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [**federated tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html)?